# Regexp - Substring delimiter multiple groups

Tags: regex

I really know very few about regular expression and i have a string like this:

```
(someval1)(someval2)
```

What i need is regular expression to select `someval1` and another to select `someval2` (or more in general, an RegExp to select the `nth` occurrence delimited by`()`).

Right now i have `\[([^]]+)\]` that select me `someval1`, but i really dont know how to select the `nth` group.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Just repeatedly match the same regex to find them all? E.g. using `re.findall` in Python or repeating `matcher.find()` and `matcher.group()` in Java?

Comment: I was thinking that exists some thing to say "select the nth group" because my context isnt Python or Java. I was thinking some general. I would like to select it in a single "line", writing the two expression, one for the first group and another one for the second group. But maybe this is not possible without a "loop" :)

Comment: You could use a regex like `(stuff){234}(stuff)` to get the 235th occurrence of "stuff". But I suggest just using a loop to get the 235th match.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for 454th then you can search with following regex:

```
^\(\w+454\)$
```

see it in https://regex101.com/

[image]

Comment: @tobias_k image is added.

Comment: Oooh, now I get it. However, I am roughly 78% sure that `someval1` and `someval2` were just dummy values and that in reality the nth entry does not necessarily end with the number n.